# Mac OS X Sandbox Apps confusion

Tags: xcode4, sandbox

I am making a small App for the Mac OS X App store with xcode/cocoa that needs read only access to folders on the user's system. The user will choose the folders.

According to Apple's specs the Sandbox will only allow access to files outside of the apps sandbox if a user's chooses it.

Does this mean, that if I present the user with a folder thru the open dialog, then the app will have read access to that and all the subfolders? Or is sandboxing only for individual files.

In addition, does the user have to repeat the process every time there is a relaunch of the App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The app will have access to all the subfolders, of the user selected folders.
2. You can use [Security-Scoped Bookmarks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html).